# Data Manipulation using filters on a column

Tags: python, pandas

dfrules contains the ruleset, dfDataset is the main dataset. Now there is an item_type column in dfDataset based on which there are rules(INT, RSU etc.). '

**Rule:** For an item dfrules['Field']['item_type'] if it is marked x, then that field cannot be NaN in dfDataset(eg: Field: Spec_Name, item_type :INT-- See image). If it does have null values, append that column name(eg: spec_name)in the created Errors column in the dfDataset.

**What is happening:** For example there is row of item_type ALL which has NaN in column Spec_Name. Now in the Errors column, i should add 'Spec_name' for that row alone. But the code that i have written adds 'B' to all rows of item_type X.[image: 1st part is dfrules dataframe, 2nd part is the dfdataset dataframe in the image attatched]

```
   for row in Rulefields:
      dfrulefields = dfRules['Field'][(dfRules[row] == "x")]
      dfrulecols = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(dfrulefields))
      dfrulecols.columns = 
      dfrulecols.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_').str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
      dfinput = dfDataset[dfDataset['item_type'] == row]
      dfmatchingfields = dfinput[dfinput.columns.intersection(dfrulecols.columns)]
      null_columns=dfmatchingfields.columns[dfmatchingfields.isnull().any()]
      dfnull=dfmatchingfields[dfmatchingfields.isnull().any(axis=1)][null_columns]
      dfinput['Errors'] = dfnull.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.isnull()].index),axis=1)
      if(firstelement == "Yes"):
        dffinal = dfinput.copy()
        firstelement = "No"
      else:
        dffinal = dffinal.append(dfinput)
```

I'm not really sure whats causing this behaviour. Please explain and possigble reolution would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly, because now without data is really complicated debug your code

Comment: please provide a dummy input data and expected output

Comment: Hi, i have attached an image of the input data and ruleset.

Answer (score 0):

Based  on the given inputs and my understanding i am providing you a solution let me know if this works for you:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        'item_type':['INT']*5 + ['RSU']*5,
        'spec_name':['a', 'b','c','d', None,'h', 'g','f','e', None]
    }
)

print df

    item_type   spec_name
0   INT a
1   INT b
2   INT c
3   INT d
4   INT None
5   RSU h
6   RSU g
7   RSU f
8   RSU e
9   RSU None

mandatory_rules = ["INT", "RSU"]
df[ "Error"] = None
df.loc[(df['item_type'].isin(mandatory_rules)) & (df['spec_name'].isna()), "Error"] = "spec_name"

print df

    item_type   spec_name   Error
0   INT a   None
1   INT b   None
2   INT c   None
3   INT d   None
4   INT None    spec_name
5   RSU h   None
6   RSU g   None
7   RSU f   None
8   RSU e   None
9   RSU None    spec_name
```